# Yum update on Fedora with option

Tags: php, linux

is possible to install PHP with option `--enable-pcntl` (compile flag) with `yum` on Fedora 14?

I would like turn on `pcntl` support for my php scripts but I don't want to compile PHP.

**Update:**

Thats it, i stuck with this problem. Its no way to find any package like `php-pcntl` for Fedora, i mus recompile php with option `--enable-pcntl` but if i have installed php with `yum`, how i recompile php? Know anybody?

Any idea how i enable pcntl on php without compile new php or with using yum service?

Comment: If you have a new question then you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

No. Configuration options in the source code are fixed when the binary package is built. The best you can do is see if pcntl has been built as a separate package, e.g. `php-pcntl`.

Comment: i dont find any of package like "*pcntl*" and i use remi sources, have you any others sources please? Thank you

Comment: Ok, i found http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/limit/7/srodzaj/1/dl/40/search/php-pcntl/field%5B%5D/1/field%5B%5D/2, thats it, add rpm source and install php-pcntl. Thanks